# Нужно создать кнопку в каждом поле таблицы HTML, которые будут взаимодейтсвовать с полями базы данных Postgresql. Делаю на Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql

В таблицу HTML выводятся данные из БД Postgres. И рядом с каждым полем должна выводится кнопка "Удалить клиента".
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка "Удалить клиента" выбирала из определенного поля информацию, прогоняла её по запросу и удаляла именно своего "клиента", т.е. каждая кнопка должна взаимодейтсвовать со своим полем и отправлять информацию на сервер. Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка понимала, какое поле нужно удалить?

Работаю на Node JS. Кнопка внизу в коде. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь!

Код HTML и EJS:

```
  <div class="container">
                    <h2>Інформація про клієнтів: </h2>
                    <table class="table table-striped  table-light table-hover table-bordered ">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr class="active">
                                <th>Фамилия</th>
                                <th>Имя</th> 
                                <th>Отчество</th> 
                                <th>Роль</th> 
                                <th>Телефон</th> 
                                <th>Адрес</th> 
                                <th>Дата рождения</th> 
                                <th>Пароль</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <%clients.rows.forEach(function(client){ %>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Фамилия %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Имя %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Отчество %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Роль %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Телефон %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Адрес %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Дата_рождения %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= client.Пароль %>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                        <% }); %>
                            </tr>
                            <form class="login-form" action = "/clientList"  autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                                <button class="nav-link text-white btn btn-success " 
                                name ="knop" type="submit"><h5><b>Удалить клиента</b></h5></button> <br>
                            </form>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <form class="login-form" action = "/clientList"  autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                        <button class="nav-link text-white btn btn-success " 
                        name ="knop" type="submit"><h5><b>Добавить клиента</b></h5></button> <br>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Не знаю как это реализуется в синтаксически, но принцип такой: 1. Отправляете запрос на нужный урл с передачей ID. 2. В ноде программно делаете что нужно в БД и делаете редирект обратно на страницу со списком данных - отобразится уже без удалённой записи список.  3. Чтобы ID записи был доступен в `form` - надо этот тэг перенести в ваш цикл, формирующий строку в таблице. Тогда, видимо, можно будет его как-то так получить: `<%= client.ID %>`